# Tkinter: unable to find a screen when running as a Systemd service

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, systemd

Refer to https://github.com/ProjectNeura/LEADS/issues/21.

```bash
 leads.service - LEADS
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/leads.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2023-12-30 21:06:07 EST; 5s ago
    Process: 2497 ExecStart=/bin/bash /usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/leads_vec/_bootloader/leads.service.sh  (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 2497 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 491ms

Dec 30 21:06:07 rp-4b1 bash[2498]:            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Dec 30 21:06:07 rp-4b1 bash[2498]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 16708, in _get_hidden_master_root
Dec 30 21:06:07 rp-4b1 bash[2498]:     Window.hidden_master_root = tk.Tk()
Dec 30 21:06:07 rp-4b1 bash[2498]:                                 ^^^^^^^
Dec 30 21:06:07 rp-4b1 bash[2498]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.11/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2326, in __init__
Dec 30 21:06:07 rp-4b1 bash[2498]:     self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
Dec 30 21:06:07 rp-4b1 bash[2498]:               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Dec 30 21:06:07 rp-4b1 bash[2498]: _tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
Dec 30 21:06:07 rp-4b1 systemd[1]: leads.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 30 21:06:07 rp-4b1 systemd[1]: leads.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

The target file:

```py
from os import chmod as _chmod
from os.path import abspath as _abspath


def create_service() -> None:
    _chmod(script := _abspath(__file__)[:-10] + "leads_vec.service.sh", 777)
    with open("/etc/systemd/system/leads_vec.service", "w") as f:
        f.write(
            "[Unit]"
            "Description=LEADS VeC"
            "[Service]"
            f"ExecStart=/bin/bash {script}"
            "[Install]"
            "WantedBy=graphical-session.target"
        )
```

Executive script:

```bash
if [ ! -x "/usr/local/leads/config.json" ];
then
  echo "Error: Config file does not exist"
  exit 1
fi
python3.11 -m leads_vec -c /usr/local/leads/config.json run
```

I tried to register this gui program as a Systemd service but it fails to boot up.

Comment: Not sure if it work for you, please refer https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/issues/4703